# Python returning Hexadecimal address instead of object

Tags: python

I'm having a bash at OOP. Here is my code.

```
class Cards:

    Suit = ['C','S','H','D']
    Rank = list(range(1,11)) + ['K','Q','J']

    def __init__(self,Suit,Rank):
        self.suit = Suit
        self.rank = Rank

    def __str__(self):
        card = '[SUIT: %s, RANK: %s]' % (self.suit, self.rank)
        return card

class Deck(Cards):

    def Show():
        return [Cards(i,j) for i in Cards.Suit for j in Cards.Rank]
```

I'd like to know why the return statement for the Show attribute in Deck is returning a list like this....

```
[<__main__.Cards object at 0x10592bc88>, <__main__.Cards object at 0x10592bcc0>,....]
```

I have had a look in my textbook, cant seem to find anything. Also done a google search, in fact, i'm not actually sure what i am looking for.

Comment: Nope. A list, but not that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because its using `__repr__`  ...

adding this to your Card class

```
def __repr__(self):
   return str(self)
```

should resolve the issue

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
# only used when printing change to __repr__
# to override the default object representation

def __repr__(self): 
    card = '[SUIT: %s, RANK: %s]' % (self.suit, self.rank)
    return card
```

Comment: Since `str(x)` defaults to `x.__repr__` in the absence of `__str__`, this is definitely the best answer

Answer (score 1):

You need `__repr__` in Cards. For example:

```
def __repr__(self):       
    return self.__str__()
```

Comment: bah you should have left it ... mine uses str and I liked the example showing him another way

Comment: @JoranBeasley Its still another way - calling `__str__` as if it was a normal method:-)

Comment: (yeah I upvoted you before you edited but still worth an upvote since we posted simultaneously pretty much (I think i beat you by a second or vice versa))

Comment: The `str` function calls the `__str__` method of the argument. It's simply a preference.

Comment: I'm gonna have to read up on this. __repr__ method, i've heard of it, reverse print, Why is it using __repr__ by default? If this is something i need to look up just tell me.

Comment: because the `__str__` method of a list prints the `repr` of each of its items ...